# Strategies for keeping multiple platforms in sync?

Tags: content-curation, reddit, twitter, wordpress

I have a small video web site (hosted with Wordpress), a subreddit, a YouTube channel and Twitter. Once in a while one of my videos gets some attention on reddit and I'm having trouble keeping my presence in all three areas in sync now.

My current process involves uploading a new video to YouTube, updating my personal site, posting a new thread in my subreddit and then finally making a Twitter post (if I feel it's warranted for this particular video). This is time consuming and requires I perform each of those steps.

I don't have commenting enabled in Wordpress. Instead I encourage people to visit the subreddit thread. This means I need to update the Wordpress post once the reddit thread is made, adding yet another step.

I'd like to focus more on the content and community that is developing, rather than managing each of these platforms. I want to keep my Wordpress site, as it's the portfolio I use to show my work.

What are some effective strategies for keeping multiple platforms in sync?

Comment: I posted a [meta question](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/is-this-technical-question-about-syncing-on-line-content-on-topic) about this one

Comment: Are you looking for a technical solution (ie. a single application) to keep everything synchronized or more generic workflow strategies?

Comment: Both, if possible. I read over the linked post and it seems that may not be allowed. If not, workflows would still be helpful.

Comment: @Overwhelmed personally, I don't think that the technical portion is off-topic either, but we won't be able to help with "platform building", just with suggesting how available tooling may be able to help and what kind of processes can help.

Comment: That sounds great @AJHenderson! That would help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In the first instance I'd look at seeing if I could automate the process of posting the same content to several sites and the process of posting announcements. This may mean that you have to change your workflow to post to a different site than you do now as it has become the "master" site that gets all the updates first and then forwards the posts onto the other sites you operate on.

I know that used to be possible to sync posts between Twitter and Facebook [but this feature was recently removed](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/link-twitter-to-facebook). This is always a risk when dealing with technological solutions built on platforms that are always evolving.

If there are no technical solutions then you are stuck with the process you have now of manually uploading the content to each site in turn. If you wish to concentrate on content creation rather than this administration work then you are going to have find someone who is prepared to do it for you. You can then produce the content and pass it to your assistant(s) for uploading. If you can get several people to help then you can spread the load so that it doesn't become an onerous task for them either.

One thing to note though - Google does penalise duplicate content so you might want to [change how you publish](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/republish-the-same-content-posted-on-subreddit/3131#3131) the content to avoid these penalties.